# A significant increased in memory usage when iterating Promises in an async function

Tags: node.js, memory, promise

I'm trying to figure out what caused the significant increased in memory usage during the iterations in the following code.

```
async function a () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            if (i%100000 === 0) {
                console.log(i)
                console.log(process.memoryUsage())
            }
            resolve(i)
        })
    }
}
a()
```

As the code runs, this memory usage jump happens several times and always happens when the i reaches some certain numbers.

### In 7.9.0, always occurs from 2000000 -> 2100000

```
1700000
{ rss: 20135936, heapTotal: 9355264, heapUsed: 6003256, external: 8772 }
1800000
{ rss: 19836928, heapTotal: 9355264, heapUsed: 4490432, external: 8772 }
1900000
{ rss: 19316736, heapTotal: 9355264, heapUsed: 5039992, external: 8772 }
<-- Jump happens between here -->
2000000
{ rss: 19357696, heapTotal: 9355264, heapUsed: 5587808, external: 8772 }
2100000
{ rss: 23605248, heapTotal: 13549568, heapUsed: 6088208, external: 8772 }
<-- and here -->
2200000
{ rss: 23601152, heapTotal: 13549568, heapUsed: 6586000, external: 8772 }
2300000
{ rss: 23568384, heapTotal: 13549568, heapUsed: 7083112, external: 8772 }
```

### In 8.3.0, always occurs from 2600000 -> 2700000

```
2400000
{ rss: 30507008, heapTotal: 9437184, heapUsed: 4785896, external: 8252 }
2500000
{ rss: 30523392, heapTotal: 9437184, heapUsed: 4710912, external: 8252 }
<-- Jump happens between here -->
2600000
{ rss: 30539776, heapTotal: 9437184, heapUsed: 4636176, external: 8252 }
2700000
{ rss: 34742272, heapTotal: 13631488, heapUsed: 6606512, external: 8252 }
<-- and here -->
2800000
{ rss: 34750464, heapTotal: 13631488, heapUsed: 8571208, external: 8252 }
2900000
{ rss: 34758656, heapTotal: 13631488, heapUsed: 6412304, external: 8252 }
```

Comment: Are both screenshots meant to be the same?

Comment: I provided 2 new screenshots which show the significant increase more clearly. The two screenshots show the result runs in nodejs7.9 and nodejs8.3. No matter how many times I try, the RSS jump happens at the same count number in a version.

Comment: Is this the extent of your program? Or is there anything else running at the same time as this loop? If there's more, could you post it (or describe it if it's too big)?

Comment: Just copy paste the code and run it in node then observe the RSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In V8 (the JS runtime that Node.js uses) a set amount of size is pre-alocated for the heap. This is the `heapTotal` you see. When V8 suspects that you are going to need more space it will increase the total size of the heap.

With your example code, what happens is that a lot of small objects get allocated on the heap. This is reflected in the `heapUsed`, and is the actual amount of memory that is being used by your code. When the heap fills up a round of Garbage Collection (GC) is performed, freeing up space. So if you plot the `heapUsed` as you increment `i` then you'll see it go up and up, until the GC kicks in and it'll drop back down.

In fact, that's exactly what I did for a *very* long run!

[image: Heap usage for 10 billion iterations]

You can clearly see that the heap is never allowed to get that big before the GC kicks in.

To further validate this we can *manually* trigger the GC in our code if we run the following using `node --expose_gc`

```
async function run() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
        await new Promise(async resolve => {
            if (i % 10000000 === 0) {
                global.gc();
                console.log(`${i}, ${(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2)}mb`);
            }
            resolve();
        });
    }
}
run();
```

From this you get the following output on `v7.9.0`

```
0, 3.12mb
10000000, 2.77mb
20000000, 2.78mb
30000000, 2.78mb
40000000, 2.78mb
50000000, 2.78mb
60000000, 2.78mb
```

## Different Node versions

What's very interesting is if we run the test on different versions of node!

[image: heap size plotted against number of iterations for different node versions]

As you can see there is a massive difference in the memory profile for pre-v8.2.0 and successive versions of node.js. If we go take a look at the [change log](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V8.md#2017-08-09-version-830-current-addaleax) for v8.3.0 we see why!

> The V8 engine has been upgraded to version 6.0, which has a significantly changed performance profile

This is the version of V8 that included [Turbofan](https://v8.dev/docs/turbofan) which implements a *sea of nodes* and included a lot of performance enhancements for the GC.

There is a more in depth view on how the V8 GC works available in Thorsten Lorenz's [v8-perf](https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-perf/blob/master/gc.md) repo.